# Django dynamic forms - validating Select field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django 2.2

I am creating a form dynamically, by reading a JSON definition file; the configuration file specifies the types of widgets, permitted values etc.

I have come a bit unstuck with the Select widget however, because I prepend a '--' to the list of permitted values in the list (so that I will know when a user has not selected an item).

This is the code snippet where the Select widget is created:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       # ...
       elif widget_type_id == WIDGET_TYPE_DROPDOWN:
            CHOICES.insert(0,('-', INVALID_SELECTION))
            form_field = CharField(label=the_label, widget=Select(choices=CHOICES),required=is_required)
```

My problem is that when the `is_valid()` method is invoked on my form, any rendered Select widgets are are accepted as valid regardless of the selection.

I want to implement code that has this logic (pseudocode below):

```
def is_valid(self):
    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
        if isinstance(field.type, Select):
            if field.required and field.selected_value == INVALID_SELECTION:
                return False

     return super().is_valid()
```

What would be the correct way to implement this functionality? For instance, how would I even get the selected values for the field (in the form code)?

Comment: What if you use `(None, INVALID_SELECTION)`? `None` instead of `-`

Comment: Potentially you can add `clean_field_name` method dynamically for select field and override the validation behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate a form data: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#using-validation-in-practice)

- by creating a custom `Field` with validation
- a specific field by using `fieldname_clean()`
- by overriding `clean()`
- by using validators

---

**?** What would be the correct way to implement this functionality?
*I've deviated a bit from the pseudocode in what you've asked*

**Validators** [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#writing-validators)

There are already many buitin validators. For this purpose, create a custom validator which checks the value in the field and raise `ValidationError`.

Create validator.py in your app

```py
# validator.py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_select_option(value):
    if value == '-':
        raise ValidationError('Invalid selection')
```

In forms.py import validate_select_option and add validator to the field

```py
# forms.py
from .validator import validate_select_option

# other parts of code

form_field = CharField(label=the_label, widget=Select(choices=CHOICES), required=is_required, validator=[validate_select_option])
```

This validator `validate_select_option` can now be used not only to the field which has choices but also to any other field to validate. Anyhow, that's not its intend. So can be used to any fields with choices :)

*Since you said that you are creating the form dynamically and I'm assuming that you can add additional options to `Field` using JSON definition file. For `fieldname_clean()` and `clean()` you will need to add these methods in your Form class. Custom field can be created and imported into. But, I think simple validators can do this easily.*

---

**?** how would I even get the selected values for the field (in the form code)

If Form class method `clean(self, *args, **kwargs)` and `fieldname_clean(self, *args, **kwargs)` are used : you can access the form data by `self.cleaned_data` dictionary. `cleaned_data` is created only after `is_valid()`.

While overriding `is_valid` , in-order to access the form data, we need to call the parent validation first and then work on it.

```py
def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # cannot access self.cleaned_data since it is not created yet

    valid = super(myForm, self).is_valid()

    # can access self.cleaned_data since it has been created when parent is_valid() has been called

    for fieldname, field in self.fields.items():
        if isinstance(field, forms.CharField): # the type of widget is not considered.
            if fieldname in self.cleaned_data and field.required and self.cleaned_data[fieldname] == '-':
                valid = False

    return valid
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hidden because you're using a `CharField` with a `Select` widget but if you look at the [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) documentation it says that the empty value should be an empty string.

Assuming the form field is `required=True`, you should just be able to change your empty value tuple to `('', INVALID_SELECTION)`.

Answer (score 0):

`CHOICES` having already values. I insert `('INVALID_SELECTION', 'INVALID_SELECTION')` this. And check if the value of `form_field` field is `INVALID_SELECTION` then add error in same field. Else form is submited.

views.py

```
class DynamicFormView(View):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = myForm( request.POST or None)
        context = { 
            'form' : form,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    
    def post(self, request,id = None, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        form = myForm(request.POST or None,)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.POST['form_field'] == 'INVALID_SELECTION':
                form.add_error("form_field",_("This field is required."))
            else:
                form.save()
        context = { 
            'form' : form, 
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [
        ('FR', 'Freshman'),
        ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
        ('JR', 'Junior'),
        ('SR', 'Senior'),
        ('GR', 'Graduate'),
    ]
    CHOICES.insert(0,('INVALID_SELECTION', 'INVALID_SELECTION'))
    form_field = forms.ChoiceField(label='the_label',choices=CHOICES,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':' form-control'}),required = False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        # form is success
        pass
    class Meta:
        model   = Student
```

urls.py

```
path('dyanmic-form/create/',  views.DynamicFormView.as_view(), name='dyanamic_form_create'),
```

Sorry my bad english language.

Comment: Are you try this ??

Comment: I updated my answer please try this - Homunculus Reticulli